# Access Apache Environment in PHP script (CLI)

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I currently have a script which will run via the browser and separately via the "php" command line tool.

Now the problem is, I am able to access the Apache Environment variables while script being called from the browser, but unable to access it while the script is called via command line.

How can I get the Apache environment available to the command line script as well ?

Comment: I hope you realise that the reason you get the environment variables when accessing the page from a browser is because the script is being run frome inside the Apache process, and when you run from the command line it is not. What OS is this on?

Comment: I would suggest that you pass the needed Apache Environment Variables to the CLI script using command line arguments.

Answer (score 5):

First, you must declare your environment variable using this command:

```
export APPLICATION_ENV=development
```

Then you can get it in your application cli with the function `getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');`.